# AWS-S3 Signed URL Security concern

Tags: aws

When you create a pre-signed URL for your object, you must provide expiration date and time. The pre-signed URLs are valid only for the specified duration.

Anyone who receives the pre-signed URL can then access the object.

We have some security issue here, considering anyone who gets this URL can access the associated resource. Do we have any mechanism where we can embed authorization as part of this presigned URL?

Like, can we add canned ACL headers as part of this URL request, so only granted users\groups can access the resource?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is too late but better late than never. You can use signed-url of cloudfront to allow user access to specific objects.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html